# html get method - two words value issue

Tags: php, jquery, html

every request with country name as an one word goes through, only "united kingdom" doesn't.

```
$("#content").load('view.php?country=united kingdom');
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with encodeURI:

```
$("#content").load(encodeURI('view.php?country=united kingdom'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Escape United Kingdom using `encodeURIComponent`, mainly to replace the space with a plus sign.

Example:

```
country = "united kingdom";
$("#content").load('view.php?country=' + encodeURIComponent(country));
```

Alternatively, use the `.load` data parameter, which is automatically escaped.

```
$("#content").load('view.php', { country: "united kingdom" });
```

Comment: Generally speaking, use encodeURIComponent for all query string parameters.